# Spring Boot: Use different Tomcat Version

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

In Spring Boot Documentation there is a section [Use Tomcat 7.x or 8.0 with Gradle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#_use_tomcat_7_x_or_8_0_with_gradle)
This works great with Maven as shown in some spring-boot-samples, but unfortunately not for Gradle.

Is there a easier solution than excluding all tomcat dependencies form tomcat-starter and add them separately with another version?

To Reproduce:
If you convert the sample project [spring-boot-sample-tomcat80-ssl](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat80-ssl) into a Gradle project with following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.4.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.4.RELEASE")
    compile("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2")
    compile("org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:8.0.36")
    compile("org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17")
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.4.2.RELEASE'
}
```

The output from `gradlew dependencies` looks like this:

```
compile - Dependencies for source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.4.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.4.2.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.4.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.4.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.7
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.20 -> 1.7.21
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.21
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.21
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.21
|    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.4.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.6
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.5.6
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.5.6
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.6
+--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.4.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4
|    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9
+--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:8.0.36
\--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17
```

Executing the `SampleTomcatSslApplicationTests` you can see the wrong Tomcat Version in Logs:

```
2016-12-21 10:20:36.713  INFO 11368 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-12-21 10:20:36.714  INFO 11368 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
```

**SOLUTION**

- use spring boot gradle plugin -> here comes the magic
- set `ext['tomcat.version'] = '8.0.36'` in build script

Comment: Did you try to follow the example on [the spring docu page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html) - bullet 70.16.2? In the example a build property `tomcat.version` is set in addition to including the `tomcat-juli` artifacts. I think this might do the trick...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I already replied you on the issue [you've created](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7715). After you've told us our documentation was wrong, I took the time to [build a sample](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/test-gradle-tomcat80) that does exactly what [is referenced in the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#_use_tomcat_7_x_or_8_0_with_gradle).

If that does not work for you, you'll have to be more specific and explain what is wrong in the documentation.