# Spring Boot 2 war file attempts to load el-api v3.0 class (NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager) on tomcat 7 (el-api 2.2)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, tomcat7

I have a Spring boot 2 gradle project That I hope to deploy as a (non-executable) war file to a tomcat 7 instance (RHEL).

I am receiving a `NoClassDefFoundError` when deploying the war to tomcat on the server:

```
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:138)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:281)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:474)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolatorConfiguredWithClassLoader(ConfigurationImpl.java:650)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:397)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:364)
        at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:501)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:132)
        ... 40 more
```

On inspection I find that the hibernate bean validation library has failed to find this particular class (`javax.el.ElManager`) during initialization.

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394504/hibernate-validator-6-0-8-jars-causing-exception) suggests adding the correct el-api v3.0 dependency to the runtime but I'm not sure this is a wise solution because the el-api v2.2 already exists amongst the shared (`providedRuntime` in gradle vernacular) libraries in Tomcat. I'm concerned about `ClassLoader` issues if I have 2 versions of the same API (Is this a reasonable concern?).

> Upgrading to tomcat 8 is a no-go, as we run tomcat7 on RHEL which currently only supports tomcat 7.

**How do I tell Spring to use javax el-api v2.2?**

#### Additional Notes

The default `tomcat.version` when depending on spring-boot-starter-tomcat seems to be `8.5.31` according to the `gradlew dependencies` command:

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.0.2.RELEASE
|    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.31
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.5.31
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.5.31
```

As I understand from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260015/spring-boot-use-different-tomcat-version), settings the gradle `ext['tomcat.version']` property to `7.0.76` (our server's version) resolves these dependencies correctly:

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.0.2.RELEASE
|    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.31 -> 7.0.76
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.5.31 -> 7.0.76
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.5.31 -> 7.0.76
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.76
```

However I still run into this `NoClassDefFoundError`. It seems to me that Spring does not recognise the correct api version and continues assuming the `ElManager` is present.

> *Thank you for your time.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Spring Boot 2.X only supports Tomcat >= 8.5.X

After trying to modify the transitive dependencies of the default spring configs (namely `hibernate-validator`), I came across documentation for Spring Boot 2's [minimum server requirements](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#third-party-library-upgrades): **`Tomcat 8.5.X`**. Alongside that, only servlet APIs of 3.1+ [are supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements-servlet-containers)

The fundamental problem I am fighting against here - which will undoubtedly produce problems down the line if I changed the dependencies - is that **Tomcat 7 is not supported by Spring Boot 2**. Any transitive library I downgrade may break some other dependency which requires its updated functionality.

Spring Boot 1.5.X [does however support Tomcat 7 and Servlet 3.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.13.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_servlet_containers) application servers. So the **solution is to downgrade to Spring Boot 1.5.X** (currently at 1.5.13 at time of writing).

Alternatively - and the solution I will be pressing with the systems team here at my workplace - Is to **instead use embedded servlet containers** (i.e. tomcat 8.5/9 embedded). Unfortunately for me, That means a long discussion into the modification of existing enterprise processes that assumes a deployment mechanism. But that is besides the point :P

Comment: You saved my day!!, BTW have you got any other way to make it working in tomcat 7 only?